# Assigning factors with levels in mixed design ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, factors

I am trying to run a 2x2x2 mixed-design ANOVA in R, but I cannot figure out how to take four of my six variable columns, which are populated with reaction times

- Animal seen face predicted (ASFP)
- Face seen animal predicted (FSAP)
- Face predicted face seen (FPFS)
- Animal seen animal predicted (ASAP)

And use them to create 2 factors (prediction and target) with two levels each (animal and face) in order to run my mixed-designs ANOVA. I know how to do this in SPSS, which I would do by sorting my variables as below:

```
Within-Subjects Variables
(Prediction, Target)
FPAS (1,1)
FPFS (1,2)
APFS (2,1)
APAS (2,2)
```

However, I haven't been able to replicate this in R.

Below is an example of my dataset, and in this case, as I don't know how to do this with two factors, I have created a single factor (condition) with 4 levels and then run the ANOVA.

```
# Set seed for reproducibility of the data
set.seed(10)

# Create a dataset of reaction times for participants after seeing an image of either an Animal or face based on whether they predicted seeing an animal or face
# Group the participants into one of two groups, group one, face experts, and group two, non-face experts

data_set <- data.frame(
  
  ID = seq(1, 100, by = 1),
  
  FPAS = rnorm(100, sd = 5, mean = 30),
  
  APFS = rnorm(100, sd = 15, mean = 100),
  
  FPFS = rnorm(100, sd = 5, mean = 30),
  
  APAS = rnorm(100, sd = 15, mean = 100),
  
  Group = sample(c(1, 2), size = 100, replace = TRUE))

#Gather the data into a single factor with four levels
df_long <-  gather(data_set, "Condition", "ReactionTime", ASFP, FSAP, FPFS, ASAP)
# Run a Mixed-design ANOVA
res <- anova_test(data = df_long, dv=ReactionTime, wid = ID, between = Group, within = c(Condition),detailed=T,effect.size="pes")

#output the findings
get_anova_table(res, correction="auto")
```